# What Should I Do With Remained Migrations?

Tags: c#, migration

During developing of my application I've made many migrations on database.

I have question:

1. Is it correct to delete all migrations and then create a single final migration?
2. If that is bad practice, so what happed when our database dose not exist and our application create database for the first time? Apply all migrations one by one?

thank you all

Comment: Is there ever a final migration?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, there are usually no "final migration" as long as you continue developing your program. For the database in production env, you should not simply delete the migrations and recreate the init migration, deleting and regenerating migration could cause data damage.

so the answer for your first question is no. you continually add migrations. In the migration class you find two methods:

1. `Up()`: represents the upgrade operations.
2. `Down()`: represents the downgrade operations, which means if you roll back, this method will be called.

You have several options to preform database update option:

1. in visual studio package manager console, after you add migration, run the following command

```
Update-Database
```

if you want to roll back or only update to specific migration:

```
Update-Database <migration name>
```

2. in your c# code, make sure to migrate:

```
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

Comment: Thank you. I got answer of my first question but, about running my application for the first time on new production environment, how all migrations apply to database? Dose application regenerate a single migration from entities or not? So how create database from all migrations? thanks

Comment: @HadiMazareei as I already mentioned, use ```Update-Database``` in package manager console